# MyEclipse doesnt accept JDK for creating Runtime

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, drools, myeclipse

I am trying to create a JBoss Runtime in Eclipse. I have added 2 JRE entries in my Eclipse - one for JDK1.7 and another for 1.8. 
Still Eclipse wont identify my 1.7 entry. See screenshots attached. 
[image]

[image]

P.S: I got my JDK 1.7 by extracting the MSI/Exe setup file using 7 zip. I have done regular installation of Java 1.8 and My Java_Home is set to 1.8 in the PC. I don't want to modify it to point to lower version as it will impact other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Your JRE definition won't be recognized as valid for the JBoss runtime if it is not a JDK. Your extraction of the JDK may have resulted in a JRE instead. Why not just run the JDK installer and change the installation folder to something other than your Program Files folder; it won't switch your system to Java 1.7 that way (I just tried this myself to check). Then define a new JRE to point to the newly installed JDK 1.7 and you'll be able to use that for the JBoss runtime.

Comment: That's what I did after trying all options. It worked. 
Now I am curious as to why and when did Eclipse/Java move away from the model of "it will work as long as you have the Java files extracted from a zip or installed using a EXE " ? When you extract the setup using 7zip, you get those jdk and jre folders and files that you get it when you are running the installer. So  I am baffled as to why MYEclipse did not accept the previous JDK path got by extracting , but was able to understand the same jdk files that were overwritten using the setup?

Comment: I don't know exactly how the JBoss connector determines whether a JRE is a JDK or not. But, if you've now fixed it, perhaps you could mark my answer as correct?